# exercises in compactness

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity, compactness

I am working on some practice problems on Compactness. (Q.1.a Chapter 1.7 in Advanced Calculus, Folland)

The question is :
Give an example of :

a closed set $S\subset R\quad$ and a continuous function $\quad \quad f:R\longrightarrow R$  such that  $\quad f(s)$ is not closed

The answer provided is $\quad{ e }^{ x }$

but perhaps I am not getting this right if we have a set $S=[0,1]$ which is closed then $f(s)$ should also be closed $f(s)=[e^0,e^1]$ isnt it ? Furthermore if I am wrong could you perhaps provide me another example that would work.

Please note this is not HW, I am just studying for finals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s true but irrelevant that $f[S]$ is closed when $S=[0,1]$: the intended $S$ here is $\Bbb R$ itself. $\Bbb R$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$, and its image under the exponential map is the non-closed set of positive real numbers.

Comment: So if we are assuming that S is R but if it is closed then it contains its boundary points so wouldnt we just evaluate $f(s)$ at these boundary points. Sorry if this seems like a silly question but I wish to understand this.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ has no boundary points in $\Bbb R$; it’s closed because it contains all of its **limit** points. (In fact every $x\in\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: @KjTada: In the context of $\Bbb R$ you can simply say that a point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if there is a sequence of distinct points of $A$ converging to $x$. And since every $x\in\Bbb R$ is certainly the limit of the sequence $\left\langle x+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$, every point of $\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I understand limit point and I understand why R is closed. My last question is would $f(x)=x$ work if not is there another function $f(x)$ that would work other than $e^x$

Comment: @KjTada: $f(x)=x$ won’t work: since it takes every set to itself, it clearly must take every closed set to a closed set. Any exponential $f(x)=a^x$ with $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$ works. So does $f(x)=\tan^{-1}x$: it takes the closed set $\Bbb R$ to the non-closed set $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)$. Yet another is $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$, which sends $\Bbb R$ to the non-closed set $(0,1]$. There are many others, but those are among the simplest.

Comment: Thankyou very very much Brian. Those examples helped a lot.

Comment: @KjTada: You’re very welcome.